# Selenium 2 cannot find Firefox profile

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

In selenium 2 in a Grid setup I'm using this to try to load a profile called 'protractor':

```
-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=protractor
```

This doesn't work, I get this error:

```
UnknownError: Firefox profile 'protractor' named in system property 'webdriver.firefox.profile' not found
```

If I start Firefox with the -p argument and protractor, like this:

```
firefox -p protractor
```

It does work. What might be going wrong here?

Comment: Did it works without grid ??
did You read firefoxdriver wiki??

Comment: not sure, and yes I read the wiki if you mean this one https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Comment: Did U start your firefox locally or on grid ???

Comment: on a grid node, with some other browsers and a nodeConfig json file.

Comment: Can U check it form machine on which grid is running (without grid commands)???

Comment: Is the profile uploaded to the remote machine?

Comment: the Firefox profile is on the machine where the node runs

Comment: "Firefox profile ... not found" Sounds like it is not!

Comment: right..hence my question I guess?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and solved this by checking the profiles directory using Firefox `about:profiles` address.
I mounted in this directory the directory with local profiles, and than it worked fine.